# Getting the last number of a time period and displaying it in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the last number of a time period of a day and display it in another column until the day changes. Below is a sample of the data that I have now.

```
DT                          no_of_records
2017-05-01 00:00:00.000     241
2017-05-01 04:00:00.000     842
2017-05-01 08:00:00.000     1049
2017-05-01 12:00:00.000     1517 
2017-05-01 16:00:00.000     1627
2017-05-01 20:00:00.000     2077
2017-05-02 00:00:00.000     151
2017-05-02 04:00:00.000     772
2017-05-02 08:00:00.000     951
2017-05-02 12:00:00.000     1114
2017-05-02 16:00:00.000     1693
2017-05-02 20:00:00.000     1992
```

Below is my desired output.

```
DT                          no_of_records   total
2017-05-01 00:00:00.000     241             2077
2017-05-01 04:00:00.000     842             2077
2017-05-01 08:00:00.000     1049            2077
2017-05-01 12:00:00.000     1517            2077
2017-05-01 16:00:00.000     1627            2077
2017-05-01 20:00:00.000     2077            2077
2017-05-02 00:00:00.000     151             1992
2017-05-02 04:00:00.000     772             1992
2017-05-02 08:00:00.000     951             1992
2017-05-02 12:00:00.000     1114            1992
2017-05-02 16:00:00.000     1693            1992
2017-05-02 20:00:00.000     1992            1992
```

Do you have any ideas on how to get the total column?

Comment: Why total? Should not be the maximum per day?

Comment: Yes, except that the project I am working on I named it total for easier understanding on my part.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `first_value` window function.

```
select dt,no_of_records
,first_value(no_of_records) over(partition by cast(dt as date) order by dt desc) as toal
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE query. You might need to convert date to integer for the join operator.

```
with cte_SumPerday
(
DateOfDay,
TotalPerDay
)
as
(
select
 cast(dt as date) as DateOfDay,
 max(no_of_records) as TotalPerDay
 group by
 cast(dt as date)
from transactions
)
,
cte_TransactionsAndDays
(
 dt,
 nr_of_records,
 DateOfDay
)
as
(
select
 *,
 cast(DT as date) as DateOfDay
from transactions
)

select
*
from cte_TransactionsAndDays T
join cte_SumPerday S on
 S.DayofDate = T.DayOfDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try doing a subquery:

```
select dt, no_of_records, total = (select max(no_of_records) from table1
                                  where convert(date,dt) = convert(date,t1.dt))
from table1 as t1
```